# Word Interop - Stop default program dialog

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-word, office-interop, com-interop

I'm using Microsoft Word Interop in a program and I'm trying to create a word application, then use it to open a document and read the number of book marks it has.

The problem is that when I create the word application on a machine where word isn't the default program for every document type (While testing I've set .rtf to open with wordpad) I get a dialog which asks me if I would like to change my default program settings for word. While this dialog is still open my code is attempting to open and access the document's bookmarks, which gives me a COMException with the message "Call was rejected by callee".

I've had a good look around MSDN's docs on interop but I've not been able to find anything helpful.

My question is this: Is there some way I can stop this dialog appearing when a new application is made? Possibly tell Word not to check for this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution at the end? Thanks.

Comment: Hey @EdwinYip, sorry but I can't remember how and if I ever solved this, it's been so long since I worked on that project

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word= new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();    
Document doc = word.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                    ref obOpenAndRepair, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);       
word.DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
```

Havent tested this but the WdAlertlevel should be set to none to avoid it from showing alerts. 
WDAlertLevel is an enum part of the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Comment: This doesn't work as the dialog shows as soon as the application is created. So I don't even get a chance to set the alert level before it appears.